# Concatenating multiple rows that differ in only one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm writing an app and I have the following tables in SQLite:

course:

```
_id | name | a | b
```

university:

```
_id | name | c | d
```

course_university:

```
course_id | university_id
```

Course_university links the courses with the universities that offer them. It's a many-to-many relationship. I need a request that would give me the following

```
course._id | course.name | course.a | university.name | university.c
```

The query I thought would work was

```
SELECT c._id, c.name, c.a, u.name, u.c
FROM course AS c, university AS u, course_university AS cu
WHERE c._id=cu.course_id AND u._id=cu.university_id
```

The problem is that if there is a course offered by more than one university, the above query will show it twice, the only difference being in the university column. Is there a way to concatenate the university names for once course, so instead of getting

```
20 | Calculus | 23 | Stanford | 5 |
20 | Calculus | 23 | Harvard | 5 |
```

I'd get

```
20 | Calculus | 23 | Stanford & Harvard | 5 |
```

In my case there might be more than 2 universities working together on one course, so if it accommodates for concatenating three rows then great. This is my first time dealing with SQL databases, so I'm not that aware of any more advanced methodology to solve this.

Comment: `SQLite` seems to support [`group_concat`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) aggregated function. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT c._id, c.name, c.a, group_concat(u.name, ' & ') as universities, u.c
FROM course_university cu join
     course c
     on c._id = cu.course_id join
     university AS u, 
     on u._id = cu.university_id
group by c._id, c.name, c.a, u.c;
```

I also changed the query syntax to use explicit, ANSI standard `join` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of these SQL functions